# Cannot read .msg file in VB .net

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I want to read .msg file VB .Net using Visual Studio 2022. Whenever I try, I am getting the below error. My sample code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim filePath As String = "C:\Email\Source\Tet.msg" 
        Dim outlookApp As New Outlook.Application()
        Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = outlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(filePath)
        Dim subject As String = mailItem.Subject
        Dim body As String = mailItem.Body
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error is below:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

Comment: You don't need Office interop, but you do need Outlook. Did you add it to your project references?

Comment: Yes dear. Whenever I added Project Reference (Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library) I get below error message

Application is ambigous in the namespaces Microsoft.office.Interlop.outlook

Comment: Which line raises that error?

Comment: What other references do you add? Excel etc?

Comment: Outlook.Application() This line gets error. No other reference added